# Xcode missing documentation

Tags: macos, xcode6

I have a Mac with OS X 10.10.2 and Xcode version 6.1.
I have just returned from a trip (on which I tried to write some code in an idle moment) and the Xcode help seemed to return "No content" for everything I tried (even something as simple as NSURLCreationDateKey).

After some hair tearing I guessed this was because I had no internet access (demonstrated when I returned to internet enabled civilisation). I have Downloaded the Documentation for OS X 10.10 and Xcode 6.1.

In desperation I rebooted to Mavericks, and could work normally (with an earlier version of Xcode).

I am planning an extended trip in remote areas, and plan to take my Mac.

Is there any way I can download the missing documentation, so I can use Xcode without internet access?

---

The suggestion by @trojanfoe revealed some interesting info (although I am not sure what it means).
Obviously there is a lot of rubbish from earlier installations.
The AppleOSX10.10.CoreReference is older than Yosemite (and presumably was an earlier Mavericks update)
I am not sure what the `com.apple.pkg.10.9.OSXDocset.bom & .plist` refer to.

~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/

```
 5 Jul  2012 com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.4_3.docset/
13 Sep  2012 com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.4_4.docset/
20 Oct 10:08 com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.6_1.docset/
 3 Nov  2012 com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.CoreReference.docset/
20 Jul  2014 com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10.10.CoreReference.docset/
13 Sep  2012 com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference.docset/
 5 Jul  2012 com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.docset/
```

~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/Library

```
       204 19 Dec  2013 ./
       136 24 Mar 20:49 ../
  20592754 31 Oct 15:10 com.apple.pkg.10.9.OSXDocset.bom
       389 31 Oct 15:10 com.apple.pkg.10.9.OSXDocset.plist
    871688 24 Mar 18:35 com.apple.pkg.5.0.DevToolsDocset.bom
       400 24 Mar 18:35 com.apple.pkg.5.0.DevToolsDocset.plist
```

Comment: I think that should work.  Have a look at the `docset`s under `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation` (or something like that).

Comment: AFTER UPDATE: OK; I would nuke the whole `DocSets` folder and recreate it by downloading the documentation in Xcode.